How to calculate the theoretical X-ray scattering for a polymer melt
I have XYZ data for a polymer that I simulated in LAMMPS. I need to generate the X-ray scattering intensity profile for my system. Does anyone know how to do this?
For reference, what I need is found in this paper, figure 9: (DOI 10.1021/ma9810565)
A sample dump file will be provided soon.
Thanks for your time.
Kind regards,
Sean

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to our community! Please review this policy: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5. Also, your post makes it look like you have asked ChatGPT to give you a script, then you have made 0 effort to figure out what it does or how it works, then you've asked us to verify for you whether or not "it's right", even though it's dozens of lines long. Is that fair? Have you even tried to run that script? I have deleted the ChatGPT part of your question for now.

Perhaps the paper that you refer to gives some clues how the figure was obtained?

The paper I reference does not explain it, no. Papers do a great job of giving a theoretical overview but usually are poor when reducing to practice.

Hi Nike, prior to posting this, I did run the script and attempt to make sense of it, and it does indeed produce a scattering profile. Someone familiar with this analysis should be able to look at the code and tell if it's missing anything.

Thanks for removing your previous comment! I was almost done posting a response, but I'm glad that it wasn't necessary in the end. I'm also glad that you ran the script and that it produced a scattering profile. I'm familiar enough with MATLAB/Octave to check whether or not it's doing the right thing, if I'm given enough information about what "the right thing" is to do. Most of the 8000+ users in this community aren't familiar with MATLAB/Octave, and also don't work on X-ray scattering (the X-ray diffraction tag that you used has only 17 questions) [cot'd]

or go through papers to figure out how it's calculated. If you can provide formulas for what you want calculated from the LAMMPS output/dump-file, I can certainly try to help. Alternatively, if there's a known scattering intensity profile that you can try to reproduce using LAMMPS combined with the MATLAB code that you have, that might be another way to verify the validity of the code.

It would also help if you can reduce the code, for example if you know that the plotting part is correct (plot(two_theta, I_q);) then you can remove the 6 lines associated with plotting, and verifying the code would seem like a more manageable task. I'm guessing that the calculation of I_q based on S_q is correct, so perhaps you could narrow the question down to asking whether or not the structure_factor calculation is done correctly? Then the code that we're verifying would be about half the size, and would seem like a much more manageable task based on our available time!

Hi @NikeDattani-NoFreeTime, I just wanted to let you know that I saw your comments and I'm working on finding the equations that I need to use for calculating the scattering profile.

Thanks for the update!

I just added a comment to the answer below that contains the equations I need to work with. There are three references that I provide links to that all deal with Debye scattering. I'm going to be working through these and would appreciate any insights you may have! Note that in the paper, it takes it to a cylindrically-averaged form, which is not necessary for me.

Thanks Marcus. I'm away from home right now and will be away for a couple weeks unfortunately. My family is in the middle of a move to about ~400km away.

I checked the paper. It describes how figure 9 was computed by referring the reader to older papers:

the spherically symmetric powder pattern scatter-
ing intensity was calculated from the atom-atom pair
distribution functions. The functions for all of the atom
pairs are available elsewhere40. Standard techniques
as discussed by Wagner49 and invoked previously22,26
were used. The atomic scattering functions are from
Alexander50.

I didn't check these references, though. I assume the calculation is based on the Debye scattering formula. It's a standard way of computing a diffraction pattern from atomic positions, derived by P. Debye in 1915. This formula was derived by spherical averaging of the intensity – that's what "spherically symmetric" refers to.
The Debye formula is applied to a finite set of atoms. If you performed your simulation in periodic boundary conditions (PBC), you might need to first generate a larger system to capture longer-range interatomic distances.
Then, instead of writing your own code, you might search what programs are already available. One of them is mine: https://github.com/wojdyr/debyer (written 15 years ago and not maintained anymore).

This is very helpful, thank you! A quick search for Debye scattering led me to this very well-laid out paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7331890/
Along with https://pythoninchemistry.org/sim_and_scat/calculating_scattering/debye_equation.html
and
https://debyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#direct-space-patterns

I didn't realize that you were the author of debyer - thanks!
